# WPF xaml Visual Studio keeps automatically changing pathway to my resource

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Having issues using a custom font in a WPF app.

To use the font, I set `FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#iconfont"` on my label. However, whenever I go to edit any of the properties of the label in xaml, Visual Studio is automatically changing the font family pathway to `FontFamily="iconfont"`, and the custom font no longer works. Any way to fix this? A setting I need to change? It's infuriating!

[image]

Edit: As long as I'm switching between properties of labels, FontFamily stays the same. But if I go to edit the properties of another type of control, and then come back to the label, FontFamily resets to "iconfont".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters let's make life easier and get your clutter cleaner by taking that long pack string and making it a defined resource in your resource dict like app.xaml, window.resources, wherever we can hit it from wherever we need.

So instead of putting `FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#iconfont"` on every single instance it's used (which can be a performance hit by the way) we do;

```
<FontFamily x:Key="IconFont">
   pack://application:,,,/Resources/#iconfont
</FontFamily>
```

We take that and plop it in your resource dictionary or wherever you want so it's referenced and loaded once from one place and made available to wherever else. Then at your instance you just do;

```
<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFont}"/>
```

Now your editor should not only stop screwing with you but you have a cleaner way of maintaining that sucker. I mean imagine if you had to change your path string, or you decide to use a different font pack, would you rather do it on every instance, or in one spot that inherits to everywhere it's used?

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Every problem can be solved with another level of indirection. Actually, this is a really clean suggestion. When you want to change from iconfont1 to iconfont2, one string replace affects the entire app.

Comment: Really good point, thank you. Added it to app.xaml and switched each instance to `FontFamily={StaticResource IconFont}"/` However, each time I go to edit a property on the label font family still switches back to `FontFamily="iconfont"`

Comment: @fuzzcan seriously? Ok, this may sound dumb but you might give the old close/restart a try because I can't think of anything that would cause that unless someones tinkered with some editor settings or something off the top of my head.

Comment: @ChrisW. Ok, tried the restart and it seems to be working. I also had another instance of Visual Studio open with an old winforms project, not sure if that was affecting it somehow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool deal, have to love the magical fixes lol, glad you got a remedy, and welcome to SO!